# Use induction and Pascal’s identity to prove that if n ≥ 1, then n choose 1 equals n choose n-1 equals n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How would I be able to prove this? I can prove Pascal's Rule, but I am not sure how to utilize it with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case for $n=1$: $C_0^1 = C_1^1 = 1$.
For the inductive step (assume it's true for $n=k$):
$$
C_k^{k+1} = C_{k}^{k}+C_{k-1}^{k}=1+k \\
C_1^{k+1}=C_1^k + C_0^k =k+1 \\
\therefore C_1^{k+1}=C_k^{k+1}
$$